# How does access checking work in type alias templates?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this code:

```
struct A
{
    template <typename T>
    using type = decltype(&T::foo);
};

class B
{
    void foo() {}
    friend A;
};

int main()
{
    A::type<B> x;
}
```

[<kbd>> Run on gcc.godbolt.org <</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxLgHZSAB1QLC62nsMTQS8fNTorG3sjJxdOdyUVMNoGAmZiAgDjU05FZUxVPxS0ggi7R2dBBVT0zKCcquLSqJiuAEpFVANiZA4AciriA1UAagBBcQAGcddZKeH54YJMIw9hJeHxAGYdAgBPDy1mI0xhgBUt7EnRheGDH1FF/ZOtgBFhrGRWPYOIKQA2U4gEA0VCtLazaYvcFXK6fZgKBTDCHiGZXG4AN1QeHQwxBEFaG1RrihcwWVGIeHMY2hUxRUM2yKm1gIwyMzGs%2BJhqNJ81GQO%2BmC2Olkm2wwwAHuDhgB6aXDZzEEggYZgXog1XDPCI5jDDwU9HMdbHaLOYaoKgq3rSVVckmjXrtVggXoAVl6pFMvQm7tQzp0cjkwwUnW6z0km047oIzu9rXaAGsQJI/gA6TiSCabACcAA4JhMs1mXRNJC7eE7etx3Z7vaRfb13QoQBNSNGvQ7SHBYDBEChUCs8OwyBQIGgB0OQMAs5tSFRB0tiE2IA4Y%2B6HNY0rtnZHSGPjvQAPK0Vhb9ukLBs0TsVfnvDEfJqdGYJtnzDi/IGJY35nKG%2BsPAOMQm56Fg25RhSRhge0ND0EwbAcDw/CCMIogoAGMhCABTaQO0qAeEkL4ALRVOgrwSDIciSDqhEAOpsKwwy0W%2BBBAYxBzoCIajIIRCokAojZ5AUGgQOYtTZKQ5hNOUsSeN4vh0GJwRyUkUkmjJCQPoU1QZPoWSVIJSRFOkqktPU2mKWZjTWGUaltB0XQ9HZFZuh6N71uKOZ/IRfzcMMwDIMgwxZimmzDBAuCECQGzhjkwx6OOppSBGBL%2BhRMhRqucakAgmDMFgLj4qQiabNwKZZq4uauK4PncJw2aSJwLpCM6VakJBxauWe9aNs2raZZ2PYQEgnQEB4n7kJQY4eIOFQ5Jg%2BBEDJMGMCw15ZqQADuQEeFBzWutWbnOklnDDBthAIBKnneb5/mBcFmwZe2WU5XlFSFRWrXtS2NY%2Bs6PUtm2sYJkmkghdwkg5tOJXcMWfycJwfx7Q9nW1t1fVPQN8Bdr2U0zcOk39tNE5wqInD5i2c5fM4S4rme660JuYG7v2%2B4EEeJ43heIjANeZ74PeBRPi%2BtZvh%2BX5nj%2BFa1v%2BgHARgfQ7ixeCQb0kbQXQK3wVwvACJIQjc2haXyDL2GFXhBHOsRBCkZsLzkbIMhUYxdGsAxTHiix1HsZxeDcbxi4CYkfiaNoFkSdoJmzbJoR%2BGHITybQkfqQZWnFGHGlCck2lJ5U5m6XUijZ9ZzSze0wYOQhjrOi5P11s6HleT5wwk8AwxkymEwd2FEWLdFEakHFhN433kgpeh0iPUD2W5fllDAxGKbhn8EY5twEwVX8EycLme2fSA3DBVmpbVQWxalrmvC12jTYA/12NDSAI1jQQE2jkPE56/NkVLRrcFrZt21drOQOl1I64ZJCnXOpdRuvkW5t07ggyeDp2gvVnu9Fq7ovod1cODbMEwD44K3j5FGv0GyKF6oDZBRUkwuhTNVHMmwyybEkJIKqnAcysKRiA1Gf10axkxt2LGSBcZDlfiIio6JkAeA8AAfXRNvGRkhuAyPFMQymC4aY3npozVW7o9xaDZseU8tYuZXj6CYu8mkhY3lFsgT85j3SSz/ABICxBdggQVuBZWu1lp/wQjrEAM4UJiHHphBwptcL4T8C%2BQOmlhKiXzuJSSxdpJKRjgpRJaSE453qCnOgRkdKBHEhnQyRdIipMsjUTJlSSgpNspwMuIZHINL2jXQ6vRVG%2BSMAoSRwx5HBSUd3BaUVjoD3ikTRK4ZNhjyNkg56M83rA1LHQv4DCmEsLYRw9wH1MEgA6lfXhN8%2BEdnvsNT8z8xHvwqDOL%2Bi1BC%2BNWhwdaW1mA7V0VXfaJC669CSqFM6BALqdNZD0wK/TF6tUofM16BUPl732e0/6xysqJmWfQxh3BmGsNcOwzhFZkYHLIZCj5khuGkLme0J8i5g7cCAA%3D%3D)

It compiles on GCC and MSVC, but makes Clang complain: `error: 'foo' is a private member of 'B'`.

Is it a Clang bug? How can I work around this issue?

---

**Edit:** The duplicate doesn't provide a workaround, so here's one.

```cpp
struct A
{
    template <typename T>
    static decltype(&T::foo) helper();

    template <typename T>
    using type = decltype(helper<T>());
};

class B
{
    void foo() {}
    friend A;
};

int main()
{
    A::type<B> x;
}
```